# How to find the function such that $\int_0^1f(x)\ \mathrm dx=e^{-4n^{2}{\pi}}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function, integral-equations

> Find $f(x)$ where:
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x,n)\ \mathrm dx=e^{-4n^{2}{\pi}} $$

Is it possible that question contains infinitely many answers?

How to solve this ?

Please provide me a hint.

Comment: Off course you have infinitely many $f(x)$ to get $\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=a$, because differently formed surfaces can have the same area.

Comment: Note that the OP edited the Question's body after it was closed, replacing $f(x)$ within the integrand with $f(x,n)$.  However the relation of the supposed two argument version of $f$ to the single argument version, still appearing in the title as well as in the body text, is not clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If such a function exists, then you may add any function whose integral between $0$ and $1$ is zero. Now you should find one particular solution. For this, a constant (with respect to $x$) function suffices.

Comment: In particular, a trivial solution is $f(x) = e^{-4n^2\pi}$.

Comment: You might want to include a way to generate infinitely many such functions: $f(x)=e^{-4n^2\pi}+k(x-0.5)$ where $k\in\mathbb R$.